# Displaying part of JSON File

Tags: php, json

This is my JSON file:

```
{"message":"yes","info":{"ID":1,"Items":[{"Name":" Jim"},{"Name":" Bob"}]}}
```

Using the code below, I'm attempting to read the JSON file and echo each value of `Name` *(which should be Jim and Bob)*, however I'm being presented with the error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';'

```
<?php
$homepage = 'jsonfile';
$data = file_get_contents($homepage);
$users = $data['Items'];
for($users as $user) {
echo $user['Name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: You never decode the json string into an array. `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($homepage), true);`

Comment: And the syntax for your for loop is wrong, you probably want to use `foreach`

Comment: @JimL Thanks for both your responses. While using a `foreach`, I'm supplied with the error `Undefined index: Items` and `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check online https://3v4l.org/qTAXb

Decode the json string using `json_decode` and use a foreach to loop through the array. Get all the name into the `$arr` array and last implode them using `implode`.

```
$json = '{"message":"yes","info":{"ID":1, "Items":[{"Name":" Jim"},{"Name":" Bob"}]}}';
$result = json_decode ($json);

$arr = array();
foreach($result->info->Items as $value){
    $arr[] = $value->Name;
}
echo "<div>".implode("</div>, <div>", $arr)."</div>"; //Jim, Bob
```

Comment: I seem to get the error `Undefined property: stdClass::$Items` and `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: I revisited the JSON file and discovered I had left something out, which may be the cause of the issue. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Thank you! And if I was add another value next to name, such as `"Age":" 42"` for example, would I just to `$arr[] = $value->Age;`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But insert into another `$arr2` not `$arr`. Or if you don't want to store then echo the `$value->Name` and `$value->Age` inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Hello again :) If I wanted to put a div around each result, how would I do this?

Comment: see update answer: `echo "<div>".implode("</div>, <div>", $arr)."</div>";`

Comment: Thanks again. Could you help me with adding more information, such as their age? I tried putting `$arr2[] = $value->Age;` under `$arr[] = $value->Name;` but only the name displays.

Comment: Also, I would like the age to display inside the same div as the name

Comment: Try your self, you will got the solution. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as it is mentioned in the comment you have to decode json to array.

Secondly, you are trying to use `for()` ([see docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)) loop instead of `foreach()` ([see docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)).

Your code should be like this:

```
$data = json_decode('{"message":"yes","info":{"ID":1,"Items":[{"Name":" Jim"},{"Name":" Bob"}]}}', true);

$users = $data['info']['Items'];
foreach($users as $user) {
   echo $user['Name'];
}
```

See [working demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d967b67872c03265bb03bebd1551e89eee2325de).

Comment: Thanks for your response. While using a foreach, I'm supplied with the error `Undefined index: Items` and `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: I tried in the sandbox and the loop part is working. Must be something wrong with your json.

Comment: I revisited the JSON file and discovered I had left something out, which may be the cause of the issue. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Remove the last }, because it makes json invalid. And `json_decode()` cannot parse it, leaving you with `null` for `$data`.

Comment: Nope, Here is another attribute _info_ added by the OP.